# Best way to handle a scheduled operation using Docker and Python

Tags: python, docker

I am using Docker to run a paho-MQTT Client in a container connected to a broker in another container. The MQTT Client saves the data from the broker in various small files in a particular volume. I would like my application to merge these files together in one big file at the end of each day, save this big file to another volume, and then delete all the small files in the old volume.

Having mainly used Python for simpler, sequential operations in the past, I'm not sure what's the best way to handle this kind of scheduled operation.

I was wondering if it's a good idea to run a python script in a separate container to do the daily file operations, or if I should just handle everything in the same container where the paho-MQTT Client is running, and possibly even in the same script as the paho-MQTT Client?

Comment: Everything you have mentioned is possible, as to what is best that is purely an opinion based question (and as such off topic for Stack Overflow). It's up to you to decide which fits your specific situation best.

Comment: An approach that doesn't depend on sharing files (either by running the batch job in actually the same script, or by pushing the fragments into some sort of job queue) will be easier to manage, FWIW.  I'd avoid trying to run two separate processes in the same container, but running a background task within the same single process is fine, as is doing the asynchronous data assembly in a separate container.

Comment: Thanks both for the answer. I ended up using apscheduler and running the background task in the same script. An issue I might be facing now is that the MQTT Client writes files continuously to that folder, even during the deleting operation.